# Android| Fetch Facebook Page feed without user login?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Even tho this question asked a lot, I'm still struggling with this issue and would be grateful if someone shed some light on the subject.
I'm trying to fetch photos from famous company page (coca-cola for example) and show it as a list-view without user login. 
So in the past I know we could get it as RSS or JSON without access token / user login.
for example

```
http://www.facebook/cocacola&feed....
```

Facebook change their SDK and now we must use access-token (correct me if I'm wrong) and things become more complicated. so as far as i understand, we need to use the graph explorer to test things out.
btw they change the feed to this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{page-id}/feed
```

I'm trying to fetch some fan/business page (like cocacola), so by putting the the page-id + feed in the graph explorer i'm getting only  name of the status and no photos (or the full post) by the page. here are the results:

```
{
 "data": [
    {
    "message": "Hola buenas me gustaría sabes donde encontrar nestea a la naranja esta buenisima gracias",
  "created_time": "2015-08-23T21:33:48+0000",
  "id": "40796308305_10154420456528306"
},
{
  "message": "Last chance to enter: Share your favorite cocktail recipe including a Coca-Cola product. One entry will win a prize pack from Blue Engine Records and be featured in the Dizzy's Club Coca-Cola menu.",
  "story": "Jazz at Lincoln Center shared Dizzy's Club Coca-Cola's photo.",
  "created_time": "2015-08-23T20:08:55+0000",
  "id": "55123734674_10153512608374675"
},
```

So my question is, What do I need to do to get all page public information ?
by the way I also tried {page-id}/posts , {page-id}/photos... none of them showing the photos.
I know that after I'm finding the right syntax in the graph explorer I need to do Facebook request, something like

```
new GraphRequest(
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
"/{page-id}",
null,
HttpMethod.GET,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

but first things first, how do I get Facebook page full JSON info with the photos and everything ?
any help would be appreciate.

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, “declarative fields” – with API v2.4 they reduced the number of fields that are returned by default, you need to use the `fields` parameter now to specifically ask for the fields you want.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I'm found out that Adding A bundle with parameters solving the problems. Do you have any idea how to get Permeant access token ? a reminder, I'm trying to fetch from a public fan Facebook page without login. Thank you so much.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending